# Entering or exiting a position on “sell bid or sell ask”

Tags: stocks, futures, day-trading

I just have a question I’m curious about 
Lets say you are long ABC and you want to get out and you decide you want to sell on the bid

Lets say the bid price is trading at 10
When hitting that “sell bid” button does it mean that you will get filled 100% but on the market bid meaning that if the bid changes you will still get a fill on the new current bid?
Or if the bid changes from 10 where you attempted to sell at down to 9.90 will it become a pending offer at the previous bid of 10?

Thank you for all the help :)

Answer (score 1):

If the buy size available at $10 bid is for more shares than you are selling then all of your shares are sold.  If the size is less than your order then your fill will depend on the type of order you place.

If you place an All Or None order and the bid size is less than your order size and then drops, you sell nothing.   If not AON then you sell whatever buy size there is at $10 and the rest of your order stays open until price recovers back to $10.

If you place a market order and your sell size is larger than the buy size at $10 then you get a partial fill at $10 and more are filled at a lower prices on the order book until your entire order is completely filled.